# How to scrape a string from webpage in R using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I have a vector with 602 URLs that starts like this:

```r
links <- c("URL1.com", "URL2.com", "URL3.com)
```

Each URL links to a webpage.

Somewhere on each of the webpages is a year in the format `YYYY` as in `2019` but it is not always in the same place.

There is only one year on each webpage and I want R to give me an output that provides the year on each webpage.

I have tried using [`rvest`](https://rvest.tidyverse.org/) but I presume I need to know the specific location on each webpage.

How can I successfully scrape the year from the webpages?

Comment: How do you identify it is the year that you want? Is that the only 4 digit number on the page?

Comment: Yes, exactly. that's the only way I can identify it.

Comment: Can you try `sapply(links, function(x) x %>% read_html %>% html_text %>% str_extract("\\d{4}"))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the number to be extracted is the only 4-digit number on page, we can read the contents of HTML and extract the 4-digit number.

```
library(rvest)

sapply(links, function(x) 
       x %>% read_html %>% html_text %>% stringr::str_extract("\\d{4}"))
```

Comment: Hey Ronak, thanks again for answering my question. Just one more question: if there are more than one matches, how would I select only the first match for each html?

Comment: I think `str_extract` only returns the first match. Are you getting multiple matches ?

Comment: That's what I thought too. There are just a few with multiple matches - I think it is because there's a copyright declaration at the bottom of some websites.

Comment: Can you try `x %>% read_html %>% html_text %>% .[[1]] %>% stringr::str_extract("\\d{4}"))` and see if that solves the issue.